# Combinational SQL count query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I have some stations stored in a simple `stations` collection:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Station A |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | Station B |
+----+-----------+
| 3  | Station C |
+----+-----------+
| 4  | Station D |
+----+-----------+
```

And I have some rides stored in the `rides` collection:

```
+----+---------------+-------------+
| id | fromStationId | toStationId |
+----+---------------+-------------+
| 1  | 3             | 4           |
+----+---------------+-------------+
| 2  | 2             | 1           |
+----+---------------+-------------+
| 3  | 1             | 1           |
+----+---------------+-------------+
| 4  | 3             | 2           |
+----+---------------+-------------+
```

I would like to create a count list of all inter-station rides between all possible pairs of `fromStation` names and `toStation` names with the result looking like this:

```
[
  {
    "fromStation": "Station A",
    "toStation": "Station A",
    "count": 1196
  },
  {
    "fromStation": "Station A",
    "toStation": "Station B",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "fromStation": "Station A",
    "toStation": "Station C",
    "count": 173
  },
]

And so on for all other combinations...
```

How do I get all possible two-pair combinations of station names and then count the number of rides among them? I'm using the latest version of Postgres.

Comment: I assumed that you have a simple station list (a table with one column) and a second table connections which combines the stations... If your layout differs, please show us some sample data...

Comment: @S-Man Great answer! However, I don't have a connections table. I only have a simple station list (one column) and nothing else. I have also modified my question to add more clarity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate rides first, then resolve IDs to names:

```sql
SELECT f.name AS from_station, t.name AS to_station, count
FROM  (
   SELECT from_station_id, to_station_id, count(*) AS count
   FROM   rides
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) r
JOIN   stations f ON f.id = r.from_station_id
JOIN   stations t ON t.id = r.to_station_id
ORDER  BY 1, 2;  -- optional order
```

Of course, that only produces combinations with actual rides. If you need to include combinations without any rides, you need an `OUTER` join to a Cartesian product of the `stations` table with itself. Something like:

```sql
-- include all combinations (even without rides)
SELECT from_station, to_station, COALESCE(count, 0) AS count
FROM  (
   SELECT from_station_id, to_station_id, count(*) AS count
   FROM   rides
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) r
RIGHT  JOIN (
   SELECT f.id AS from_id, f.name AS from_station
        , t.id AS to_id  , t.name AS to_station
   FROM   stations f CROSS JOIN stations t
   ) s ON  s.from_id = r.from_station_id
      AND  s.to_id   = r.to_station_id
ORDER  BY 1, 2;  -- optional order
```

Again, it's cheaper to aggregate rides *before* joining to stations.

To wrap it up as JSON array or records, simply:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(sub)
FROM  (
   -- query from above
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=715958eec99637040f2e1a1a4c2e576b)*

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Apologies for changing the schema of the tables yet again (I took another look at my database and realized my mistake). Could you take a look at the updated question?

Comment: @DakshShah: I adapted accordingly. For your next question, please remember to provide proper information from the start. It's obviously less than ideal to change the nature of the question after answers have been given.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for the trouble! I'll ensure I do that.

Answer (score 1):

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d769a4705e7d3a1a529fdf9ecd7b9d07)

```
SELECT 
    c.from_station,
    c.to_station,
    COUNT(*)
FROM stations s1
JOIN stations s2 ON s1.station <> s2.station                                     -- 1
JOIN connections c ON s1.station = c.from_station AND s2.station = c.to_station  -- 2
GROUP BY c.from_station, c.to_station                                            -- 3
```

1. Create a self-join on the station table. The `<>` join condition ensures that same station will not be joined. All other station will be joined on each other, which creates all combinations
2. Join this result on your connections table using both station columns from the self-join for the `from` and `to` points of the connections
3. Now you can group by `from` and `to` and `COUNT(*)` aggregate this.

If you want to recognize cases where `from` station equals `to` station, you can change

```
JOIN stations s2 ON s1.station <> s2.station
```

into a simple:

```
CROSS JOIN stations s2
```

If you want to get a JSON object as you shown in the question:

```
SELECT 
    json_agg(connection)                      -- 2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        json_build_object(                    -- 1
            'fromStation', c.from_station,
            'toStation', c.to_station,
            'count', COUNT(*)
        ) as connection
    FROM stations s1
    JOIN stations s2 ON s1.station <> s2.station
    JOIN connections c ON s1.station = c.from_station AND s2.station = c.to_station
    GROUP BY c.from_station, c.to_station
) s
```

1. Create your JSON object from your columns which you created above
2. Aggregate them into a JSON array.